# Android tabbed activity and java code?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, tabs

I have 3 tabs in my tabbed activity. I created 3 classes that extend Fragment and added my layouts. When I run it, it works fine. So I added some EditText widgets and a Button to my second tab. My question is :  where do I put java code, for example, to handle onClickListener for that button.
I tried to do it in that main tabbed activity class but then the app crashed.

Comment: If you need the code, just make a new project in Android Studio and choose "Tabbed Activity" instead of "Empty Activity". You will find a perfect code and you can refer from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put that code in the relevant fragment of tabbed activity.
Application will crash because activity can not access the views which are inflated in fragment.
You can do like this :

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
        return view;
    }
}
```

For more check this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout).

Answer (score 0):

You must add button click code to respective Fragment i.e. second tab in your case.  Don't write code on activity which host that fragment.

Comment: But in that Java file I can't use findViewById

Comment: Make use of this code on your second fragment
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);
 
  
  final Button recyclerView = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
  //Add button click code here
  return view;
}

Comment: @slaven you have to use view.findviewbyid in fragment